# AWS StateMachine AccessDeniedException in step: CleanUpOnError

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-step-functions

I am getting the following error when trying to execute step function on the lambda

```
"errorType": "AccessDeniedException",
  "errorMessage": "User: arn:aws:sts::14161:assumed-role/serverlessrepo-Functi-cleanerRole/serverlessrepo-=Function-p-cleaner is not authorized to perform: lambda:functionname on resource: arn:aws:lambda:function:functionname because no identity-based policy allows the lambda:functionname action",
```

```
Resources:
  FunctionExecutionRole: # Execution role for function
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: [
                "sts:AssumeRole",
                "lambda:InvokeAsync",
                "lambda:InvokeFunction"
            ]
            Resource: "*"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambda_FullAccess
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchReadOnlyAccess 
      Tags: 
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Sub '${ApplicationTag}'
  Function1:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # Find or Create alias lambda function
    Properties:
      PackageType: Image
      ImageConfig:
        Command:
        - function1.lambda_handler
      ImageUri: 
      AutoPublishAlias: live # This property enables lambda function versioning. 
      Role: !GetAtt FindOrCreateAliasExecutionRole.Arn
      Tags: 
        Application: !Sub '${ApplicationTag}'
```

I do not have permission to change user's IAM roles/policies/permissions

Answer (score 0):

you want your lambda function to invoke a step function. However, your lambda execution role does not have permissions to invoke step functions.

What you would need at least is `states:StartExecution`
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_StartExecution.html

Without making changes to this role I don't see much you can do about it. The only theoretical solution would be to use sts:AssumeRole to assume another role with the necessary privileges (if such a role exists and has a resource policy allowing your lambda function to assume it).

Comment: I have added getAliasLambdaRole, with AWSLambda_FullAccess permission. How can I add it to my function. I am new to AWS so it will be helpful in understanding that. Thanks

Comment: AWSLambda_FullAccess ["grants full access to Lambda actions and other AWS services used to develop and maintain Lambda resources"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-identity-based.html) but not permissions needed to start a step function (which is the action `states:StartExecution`). 
Also you cannot add another role to your lambda. What you can do is adding policies to the role you are using or using a completely different role.